# Aggregate Multiple columns with different agg functions in Pandas using Crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have a dataframe of the below format. Let us call it df

| flag1 | flag2 | type | count1 | count2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | new | 10 | 2 |
| a | y | old | 40 | 5 |
| a | x | old | 50 | 6 |
| a | y | new | 15 | 1 |

I am trying to get the following format. (I could not merge the adjacent cells of count1 and count2)

|  |  | count1 |  | count2 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | new | old | new | old |
| a | x | 10 | 50 | 2 | 6 |
| a | y | 15 | 40 | 1 | 5 |

I tried the following when i had to do the aggregate on only one column (count1) and the following worked:

```
pd.crosstab([df.flag1,df.flag2], df.type, values=df.count1, aggfunc='sum')
```

But since i want two columns of data, both count1 and count2, I tried the following but did not work out

```
pd.crosstab([df.flag1,df.flag2], df.type, values=[df.count1,df.count2], aggfunc=['sum','sum']) #trial1
pd.crosstab([df.flag1,df.flag2], df.type, values=[df.count1,df.count2], aggfunc='sum') #trial2
```

None of them worked.

**Extension** :  I should be able use different functions on the different columns. say *sum on count1 and nunique on count2* **or** *sum on count1 and mean on count2*

Answer (score 1):

I think `crosstab` is not possible use here, alternative is [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['flag1','flag2'], 
                    columns='type', 
                    aggfunc={'count1':'sum', 'count2':'nunique'})
print (df)
            count1     count2    
type           new old    new old
flag1 flag2                      
a     x         10  50      1   1
      y         15  40      1   1
```

Another alternative with aggregation:

```
df = (df.groupby(['flag1','flag2','type'])
        .agg({'count1':'sum', 'count2':'nunique'})
        .unstack())
print (df)
            count1     count2    
type           new old    new old
flag1 flag2                      
a     x         10  50      1   1
      y         15  40      1   1
```